# Need Job-dsl Syntax for the password parameter

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

I need jobdsl syntax for getting the password parameter in code. I have tried few syntax everything getting failed

```
eg: password {
       name('TEST_ADMIN_USERNAME')
       defaultValueAsSecret('foo')
       description('User name with the admin privilege')
       trim(false)
   }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Job DSL:**

Within a job DSL, you can use [nonStoredPasswordParam](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#method/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.BuildParametersContext.nonStoredPasswordParam), to provide a password. The `nonStoredPasswordParam` parameter is provided by the [Mask Passwords](https://plugins.jenkins.io/mask-passwords/) plugin, hence need to install the plugin as well. The parameter declaration would look something like the below:

```
parameters {
    nonStoredPasswordParam('TEST_ADMIN_USERNAME', 'User name with the admin privilege')
}
```

**Declarative Pipeline:**

In a declarative pipeline defined within a `pipeline {}` block, using the `password` parameter specifying the names of the method arguments explicitly works. Something like below:

```
parameters {
    password(
        name: 'TEST_ADMIN_USERNAME',
        description: 'User name with the admin privilege'
    )
}
```

Comment: This did not work for me - are you sure this is Jenkins Job DSL and not Jenkins Pipeline syntax?

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out - I had indeed mixed up Job DSL and declarative pipeline syntaxes. I have updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

I am still searching for it from a long time, only find one ticket from 1 year back and still no solution " https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/pull/1044 "

I can see "nonStoredPasswordParam" on dsl wiki. still figuring out how it works.

nonStoredPasswordParam('myParameterName', 'my description')

Will follow your question if we get any answer. Thanks!